# How to install for the person that can't make sense of the how to page

Tags: boot

So I am trying to figure out how to use Ubuntu for the first time. Zero linux experience. Unless you count using my android phone that came that way.

Anyway I downloaded the desktop Ubuntu. How do I make that a bootable USB. I have looked at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

The ubuntu file is an ISO so those instructions defie my sense of logic. To be clear I did burn it to a disc to see if I could find the "start up disc creator". The answer is no that isn't on the ISO.

Mind you that I do not want to overlay Ubuntu onto windows. I don't want it side load or sharing the same disc as windows. I want to install it to its own disc to be the native OS for that disc. The ISO seems to be an installer for windows.

I will be using windows of course to make the usb install drive. That is as much relationship as I want the two to have though.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to make a bootable DVD/CD? On Windows you just download the .iso file and click 'burn'. You should check the 'verify disk' option if it asks for it. I have installed Ubuntu on 7 different computers, and in my experience I have found disks to me infinitely  more reliable then USB sticks/drives.

Comment: I may go this route because it sounds easiest at this point.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this Windows based Tool for creating your USB bootable drive:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

make sure you backup all data on the usb drive because this will erase any data on it.

Once the USB drive is created and you reboot you system and the installer starts you will be asked if you want to replace windows or install along side windows so make sure to pick install alongside. the Installer will then continue on to let you re partition your drive example: if you have a 500GB Hard disk you can give 250GB to windows and the other 250GB to Ubuntu.

Comment: When I am ready to instal ubunto my windows drives will all be disabled. I am wanting two OS's one computer. But, I do not want them together. That would create resource issues that hamper the purpose. Apparently you can't use enter to make paragraphs here so insert paragraph here.    The rig is a gaming rig. Right now win7 is eating up so many resources that I believe it is the reason I am having issues. My goal is to make my first linux run, install the game planetside 2 (Since it has a linux installer), and run it better on linux.

Comment: Also I don't want to run linux from USB I just want the installer on USB. I want the USB to install ubunto to a SSD drive.